# Cron not working consistently in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, cron

I could not get regular unix cron to work with nodejs so I am trying to use [node-cron](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron) instead.

My problem is that it seems to run inconsistently, if at all. Sometimes I will see logging occurring that indicates it is running, sometimes I will not. Why? Is there some trick to getting it to work that I am missing? Here is my code:

In app.js I have a start function that bootstraps everything for my app. In it I have this:

```
runcron.checkstuff.start();
```

runcron is defined as:

```
runcron = require('./lib/cronjobs')
```

That required file, `./lib/cronjobs.js`, is:

```
'use strict';

var cronjob = require('cron').CronJob,
    logger = require('./logger').winston();


var runcron = {
    checkstuff: new cronjob({
        cronTime: '*/5 * * * *',
        onTick: function () {
            logger.info('in cron onTick...');
        },
        start: true
    })
};

module.exports = runcron;
```

It's my understanding that I should see my logged message "in cron onTick..." every 5 minutes given that setup. Sometimes after I start my app I see it, sometimes I see it once and then not again, sometimes I never see it. What could be causing this inconsistency?

Is it possible that there are multiple processes getting spawned somehow? Maybe conflicting in some manner? I'm stumped.

Comment: `start: true` means that it will start automatically, if you want to start it manually via `runcron.checkstuff.start();`, use `start : false`. also, in `node-cron`, the first timing entry is seconds and not minutes like it is in unix cron, so yours actually says "run every 5 seconds".